How can i check my function is invokes with new keyword
I've following function
function Client(url,name){
  this.name = name;
  this.url = url;
}

Client.prototype.check = () => (...some logic);

const client = new Client(url, name)

How can I add a condition that the function is not being called without new keyword

You can use new.target meta property which return a reference to the function that new was called upon.
function Client(url, name) {
    if (!new.target) {
        throw new TypeError('calling Client without new is invalid');
    }
    this.name = name;
    this.url = url;
}

When the client is called without new then new.target is undefined
MDN Docs

Best option - rewrite as a class:
class Client {
    constructor(url, name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
    }
}

new Client(); // ok
Client(); // TypeError

If there's some reason you can't do that, you can use new.target:
function Client(url, name) {
    if (!new.target) {
        throw new TypeError('Must be called with `new`!')
    }
    this.name = name;
    this.url = url;
}

new Client(); // ok
Client(); // TypeError


if someone tries to invoke Client without using new, it will throw an error.
The this instanceof Client check ensures that the function is called as a constructor.
You can add conditions.
if (!(this instanceof Client)) {
        throw new Error("Client must be called with 'new'");
    }

